# xslt map for each loop

Tags: dictionary, xslt, foreach

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
    xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
```

I have the following map:

```
    <xsl:variable name="tabsNames">
        <entry><name>A</name><value>one</value></entry>
        <entry><name>B</name><value>two</value></entry>
    </xsl:variable>
```

I would like to iterate the map to get each key and value assigned to a variable:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$tabsNames/element()">
     <xsl:variable name="tabName" select="./entry/name"/>
     <xsl:variable name="tabValue" select="./entry/value"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How should the select look like in order to get name and value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a variable alone does nothing but given your variable with a temporary tree containing some `entry` elements if you want to process them with `for-each` and have the `name` and `value` in your variables inside of the `for-each` use e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$tabsNames/entry">
     <xsl:variable name="tabName" select="name"/>
     <xsl:variable name="tabValue" select="value"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Given the namespaces you have shown in your edit of the question you have two choices, either you need to make sure your temporary elements in the variable do not end up in the default namespace `xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"` you have on your stylesheet, you can do that with

```
<xsl:variable name="tabsNames" xmlns="">
    <entry><name>A</name><value>one</value></entry>
    <entry><name>B</name><value>two</value></entry>
</xsl:variable>
```

then my suggestion above remains valid, or you need to adjust your paths with e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$tabsNames/ss:entry">
     <xsl:variable name="tabName" select="ss:name"/>
     <xsl:variable name="tabValue" select="ss:value"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="$tabsNames/entry" xpath-default-namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
     <xsl:variable name="tabName" select="name"/>
     <xsl:variable name="tabValue" select="value"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: When I use $tabsNames/entry instead of $tabsNames/element() the loop is not not executed

Comment: Then use `element()` and next time you post show enough context to allow us to see any relevant in scope namespaces.

Comment: The suggested approach works fine for me at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/jyyiVhf in a minimal but complete sample. I suspect in your context you are dealing with some namespaces but you need to show the context to allow us to help with that.